# imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image

Tags: php

I get this error when using `$image = imagecreatefrompng($file);`

```
imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image
```

PNG support in php.ini is activated.

This message even exists, when deactivating ‘interlace’ with the help of:

```
imageinterlace($img, false);
```

newest linbpng version: libpng 1.6.37

ImageMagick can't be used

Any ideas? Tried everything

Comment: Seems to be a regression/bug. I believe `imageinterlace` is just for jpeg, not applicable to png.
Apparently you may be able to work around it if you run this prior to using the GD functionality: `exec('mogrify -interlace none *.png');`

Answer (score 2):

To suppress the error you can use:

```
 $image = @imagecreatefrompng($PathToImage);
```

Hope this helps, this looks to be a php issue and not a code related one.